# How to change existing OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom value in owl api?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Consider following Datapropertyassertion axiom

DataPropertyAssertion(http://www.sample.com/ontologies/Blank#demo http://www.sample.com/ontologies/Blank#node "value"@en).

I need to update object value with new instead of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

OWLAPI axiom instances are immutable, therefore to update one you have to remove it and add a new axiom with altered values.

Comment: thanks it's really helpful. and suppose my owl file have a individual A and that have 4 dataproperty assertion axioms.Here S1 is Subproperty of P1 and P2. 
<individual: A> <Data property : P1> <data:x1>
<individual: A> <Data property : P2> <data:x2>
<individual: A> <Data property : S1> <data:x3>
<individual: A> <Data property : S1> <data:x4>. if I remove data property assertion axiom with data:x3 it also remove <A><S1><x4> axiom. is there is any way to persist <a><S1><x4> axiom.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Please add an example to your question so we can work out the solution.